Why should I close a CachedRowSet object?
I have a CachedRowSet object in Java. Since CachedRowSet objects are disconnected from the DB, is there a need to close them, or put them in try-with-resources blocks? My IDE is suggesting I should.
Here is how I am using it, I fill the CachedRowSet from a query (and use try-with-resources for the PreparedStatement and ResultSet objects)
public static void resultSetParsing(Connection con) throws Exception {
    String sqlStatement = " select id, name from TestTable ";

    CachedRowSet cachedRowSet = null;

    try(PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlStatement)){
        try(ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()){

            cachedRowSet = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();

            // Fill the CachedRowSet from the ResultSet
            cachedRowSet.populate(rs);
        }
    }

    // I am disconnected from the DB at this point
    while(cachedRowSet.next()){
        System.out.println("Found item: " + cachedRowSet.getString("id") + " " + cachedRowSet.getString("name"));
    }
}

It has close(), which suggests maybe it should be closed. But it also extends RowSet which extends ResultSet, so I am guessing that is the reason it has close(). But the use case for a CachedRowSet logically doesn't make sense to have to close it the same way, since it can be used to work with rows while not keeping the database connection open.
So does it matter that I am not closing it at the end? I want to use this object properly.

CachedRowSet :: release() vs. close()

If you intend to reuse a Closeable object then obviously, you shouldn't close it.  Otherwise, the fact that an object is Closeable implies that you should close it in the normal course of events.  After all, if it didn't matter, why would the API designers include a close() method?  There are some cases where the method has to be there and the implementation of close() does nothing.  However, if the close() call does nothing, the JIT compiler can typically inline and then optimize away the call.  (And if not, the overhead is probably negligible.)

That is the reason I am asking. It has close(), which suggests maybe it should be closed. But it also extends RowSet which extends ResultSet, so I am guessing that is the reason it has close(). But the use case for a CachedRowSet logically doesn't make sense to have to close it the same way, since it can be used to work with rows while not keeping the database connection open.

@jabe That Comment should have been part of your Question.

@jabe To satisfy your curiosity, I suggest you peruse the source code for an open-source implementation of a concrete class implementing that interface.

Yeah, just because it does nothing when you close it now, doesn't me it will stay this way. On the other hand, I'd question the use of cached resultsets altogether. While it's nice and all, why not just you know, read the data from it and save it somewhere permanent

Usually you don't need to close such objects if you reuse them. But it is very recommended you do it anyway.
Even it it works without memory leak or other side effects now, you cannot be sure it stays working in the next version of the library.
